# Empty folders in work

Tags: sas

in my SAS work folder on Windows, I have several empty folders with strange names, like these:

```
2mfsekmw
4ug65aej
642u2k27
```

Do you know what these are and if it is possible to avoid having them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are utility folders, and are needed for the functionality of certain aspects of SAS (particularly EG, which is usually responsible for these).  They will be automatically cleaned up when SAS exits.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think that is correct. The utility folders have a different name, like this: SAS_util000400002044_computername

Comment: That's one kind of utility folder, but these are also utility folders (in the sense that they're temporary folders used for a particular purpose).  The ones named that way are used for sorts primarily, IIRC, and other things that can't fit into memory; these are used primarily for EG functionality.

Comment: Looks like you are correct, sorry. i fired up EG and the folder was created. It also got removed when I closed EG. So, the ones I see must be from sessions that have not been closed properly.

Comment: Yep.  I can't find a reference for exactly what they are used for, but I suspect they may be related to the EGTASK and EGGRID libraries.

Comment: Here is the SAS Note that explains this. Looks like it is fixed in a hotfix as well: http://support.sas.com/kb/47/304.html